# Application won't show up in market on xoom after 3.1 upgrade

Tags: xoom

Here is my manifest with everything accept activities.

You can view the app in the market, but says it is not compatible with xoom when you access the app via your xoom.  The app doesn't do anything off the phone or use gps etc...

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pragmaticpat.playroomhd&feature=search_result

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.pragmaticpat.playroomhd"
      android:versionCode="12"
      android:versionName="1.92">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="12"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/playroom_icon"
             android:label="PlayRoom HD"
             android:debuggable="false"
             android:name=".GlobalState">
    <activity android:name=".GameStartUp" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```